# Running code outside node.js thread loop

Tags: node.js, event-loop

I am new to node.js.
I already researching how to run my code outside node.js thread loop (event loop) on google but cannot get the answer.

how can i create an function that run outside node event loop.
for example, in mongoose, it use

```
scheme.save(function(err)){ 
  console.log('saved');
});
```

to insert data, where node run the insert code (save function ) outside event loop and then back to event loop to run my callback( in the above sample, doing some logging).

i try

```
  function getUser(id, callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('executed');
      callback(null, "jhon");
    }, 5000); 
  }

  function display(err,user) {
      console.log(user);
  }

  getUser(432, display);
  console.log('this show first');
```

but it run synchronously ( it block the event loop for 5 second before new request is handled ).

how can i implement the same 'save' function so it will not block event loop for 5 second in above code? 
any topic to read? 
thanks.

Comment: Why do you think it blocks the event loop?

Comment: please read updated question.
i try to run above code on 2 separated tab. and the 2nd log 'this show first' is logged after the first 'jhon' log is appeared. is iam doing it wrong?

Comment: it print something like:
   "this show first"
   "jhon"
   "this show first"
   "jhon"

instead of
`   this show first
   this show first
   john
   john`

Comment: You must be observing something incorrectly.  @shershen answer is correct.

Comment: i do some more test. and yup, its not blocking if i request another route.
but why if i request same route ( route with settimeout above) its look like the second request is blocked. iam confused

Comment: what if in the getUser function iam doing some long running code like fetching rss data? will it block its event loop or automatically creating new process for me? that the real question. settimeout is just my approach to simulate long running code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @SteveCampbell said - you're wrong assuming that `setTimeout(function() { /// }, 5000)` will BLOCK the event loop - it won't. 
It will **just delay the execution of the code inside the function for 5 sec**.

While those 5 sec last, NodeJS engine is fully operable and can do other actions, receive and send network requests and perform any other I/O.

[image]
Check on of those resources on the NodeJS event loop nature and ways to make correct use of it:

- https://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-event-loop/
- https://nodesource.com/blog/understanding-the-nodejs-event-loop/
- http://abdelraoof.com/blog/2015/10/28/understanding-nodejs-event-loop/

UPD

"code like fetching rss data" - is again **only creating a task** and adding a callback that is executed when task is done. It's not blocking anything, that's the main cool idea behind NodeJS async code.
Check here [example rss reader in NodeJS](https://github.com/danmactough/node-feedparser):

```
//1 - task configuration
var req = request('http://somefeedurl.xml')
  , feedparser = new FeedParser([options]);

// here while rss is being retrieved in a separate sub task
// nodejs engine can do other tasks

//2- callback for error
req.on('error', function (error) {
  // handle any request errors
});
//2- callback for response with data 
req.on('response', function (res) {
 //...
```

Comment: please read updated question. i try to run above code on 2 separated tab. and the 2nd log 'this show first' is logged after the first 'jhon' log is appeared.  
 
it print something like: "this show first" "jhon" "this show first" "jhon" instead of "this show first" "this show first" "john" "john"

Comment: what if in the getUser function iam doing some long running code like fetching rss data? will it block its event loop or automatically creating new process for me? that the real question. settimeout is just my approach to simulate long running code

Comment: i read http://abdelraoof.com/blog/2015/10/28/understanding-nodejs-event-loop/. its say that "All I/O is performed asynchronously by the threads in the thread pool". is node automatically create thread pool for our io code or i need to do it my self?

Comment: ah, so i need to study about eventEmitter.
thanks for the answer.

Comment: yes, just was planning to add comment about eventEmitter - a channel to communicate between processes while their callbacks are not triggerend